# Ruby on Rails Search filed drop-down that filers items from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropdown

I am trying to create a dropdown that allows selection ONLY from items in a table column. Since there are thousands of items my simple dropdown is not practical, so I was hoping to create a search field where the user can begin typing out the name of the item and it alters the dropdown so they can select an item from the able ONLY. I know this is hard to picture but something similar to this: http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3

I am quite new to Ruby and have searched quite a bit to find a solution, but I do not know exactly what to search for to complete this task. I am hoping that you can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to use this would be to use a library such as Select2: https://select2.github.io/ or chosen: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. It will do all the filtering work for you. Check out the demos.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Select2 it seems like a very useful resource. Ideally I would like to be able to use a collection_select but have the searchable dropdown is this achievable with Select2 and rails ? Is there an example of how to implement Select2 with a collection_select? I have searched and not found any way to do this. Please make a suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Searching a collection_select is surprisingly easy. Here is how I did it. 
Install the select2 gem

```
gem "select2-rails"
```

Require the javascript and css

```
#application.js
//= require select2

#application.css
*= require select2
*= require select2-bootstrap
```

Get the 'id' of the collection_select you are trying to sort through and put this in the corresponding .coffee file

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#collection_select_id_here').select2({ width: '75%' })
  return
```

I found the width was needed otherwise the box would be way too small.